# $L^p-$bound of the gradient

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary. If $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, is there some kind of "inverse" Poincaré inequality such that we can control the $L^p(\Omega)-$norm of $\nabla u$ using some norm for $u$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, take a weakly differentiable function that oscillates wildly around $0$, but is bounded by some $\epsilon>0$.

To be precise: Let $\Omega =(0,1)$. Assume we find $C>0$ such that for all $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ we have  $$||\nabla{u}||_{L^{p}} \le C ||u||_{L^{p}}$$

Then let $u_{n}$ be the piecewise linear function of $n$ bumps of height $\frac{1}{n}$ and width $\frac{1}{n}$. Then the $L^{p}$-norm is bounded by $\frac{1}{n}$, but since $|u'|=1$ almost everywhere (weakly), we have $||u'||_{L^{p}} = 1$

Letting $n \rightarrow \infty$, we have a contradiction to existence of such $C$.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I had hopes because I've seen some reverse Poincaré inequalities in the context of geometric analysis, see: [this](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~torresm/lecture-notes/geometric-measure-theory/Geometric-lecture31.pdf), [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.00603.pdf), [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/sets-of-finite-perimeter-and-geometric-variational-problems/the-reverse-poincare-inequality/D7E5D00B25F8D869C242EFA50C9B0030).
Thank you very much for your answer!